# Print text from specific line number of an HTML file

Tags: html, bash, text, grep, line-numbers

I'm trying to find a way to print the text from a specific line number of an HTML file.

I've found ways to print the *line numbers* of a *text* search, but I want to do the reverse, printing the *text* of the *line number*, where the line number stays constant but the text there may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way

```
$ cat foo.txt
dog
bird
monkey

$ sed '2!d' foo.txt
bird
```

In simple terms, `if not line 2, delete`